# How can I have a dependency for HAML in my gem when the project doesn't have HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dependencies, rubygems, haml, gemfile

Can I use Haml templates inside my gem, without write inside application Gemfile **gem 'haml'**?

I put in my_gem.gemspec file this line:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "haml", "~> 3.0"
```

I put in Gemfile of my_gem folder this line:

```
gem 'haml', '~> 3.0'
```

I do: bundle, and Haml install at this moment , but it doesn't work, and I have

```
Template is missing
Missing template layouts/my_gem with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee] }
```

Only when I duplicate in application Gemfile

gem 'haml', '~> 3.0'

It's work fine.

Can I use Haml with my gem without duplication into Gemfile?

Comment: **Solution** is: **require 'haml'** into **My_gem.rb**. Any application (Engine) should require all needed gems

Answer (score 2):

Any application (Engine) should require all needed gems, for example for me:

```
require "haml"

require "the_role/hash"
require "the_role/engine"
require "the_role/version"
require "the_role/the_class_exists"

module TheRole
  # some code here
end
```